# How many list of website element or part like according, jumbotron etc?

Tags: html, css, web

Can anyone tell me the list of part that a website need like.. Header,Footer,Accordion, Jumbotron etc
For learning to get better web developer.I'm completely new in this development sector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need are a check list for HTML structure for User Interface Design.

Here is the guide https://careerfoundry.com/en/blog/ui-design/ui-element-glossary/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need but this is a good guide: https://frontendchecklist.io/